# What about running wsdl2java inside your program?

Tags: java, apache, cxf-client

I want to generate the stubs classes from the provided wsdl url using java program. Without any tools or without command prompt option.

Comment: Use `xjc` command with Processbuilder

Answer (score 0):

Rather I would suggest you to use  [maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki)

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>your package name</generatePackage>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>http://localhost:8080/ws/some.wsdl</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```